# Forwarded port is Closed / Filtered outside the network and Open inside the network

Tags: iptables, vpn, openvpn, port-forwarding

I'm trying to forward a VPN port to the open internet to create remote office network. My VPN connects properly when I'm inside the Office network, however the VPN does not properly connect outside of the Office network. I have a Fresh Tomato (2022.6) router using AT&T (Fiber) ISP which supports port forwarding to the open internet.

For the sake of example, I want to forward the HTTPS protocol and not the VPN protocol to the open internet. Here is what I get when I check the port in the network.

```
> nmap -Pn -p443-443 homenet****.duckdns.org
Starting Nmap 7.93 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-11-25 21:14 CST
Nmap scan report for homenet****.duckdns.org (87.8.12.16)
Host is up (0.0022s latency).
rDNS record for 87.8.12.16: wan1-ip.lan

PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
```

However, when I move off the network such as a nearby cellular tower. Then perform a port scan, I get the following result.

```
> nmap -Pn -p443-444 homenet****.duckdns.org
Starting Nmap 7.93 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-11-25 21:09 CST
Nmap scan report for homenet****.duckdns.org (87.8.12.16)
Host is up.
Other addresses for homenet****.duckdns.org (not scanned): 2607:7700:0:4:0:2:2523:3333
rDNS record for 87.8.12.16: 87-8-12-16.lightspeed.rcsntx.sbcglobal.net

PORT    STATE    SERVICE
443/tcp filtered https
444/tcp filtered snpp
>
```

My Fresh Tomato Linux firewall (using iptables) gives the following result.

```
> iptables -S
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N shlimit
-N triggers
-N wanin
-N wanout
-A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j shlimit
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i br0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m limit --limit 3/sec -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 30 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m limit --limit 3/sec -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 33434:33534 -m limit --limit 3/sec -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i vlan2 -p esp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i vlan2 -p ah -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i vlan2 -p udp -m udp --dport 500 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i vlan2 -p udp -m udp --dport 4500 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i vlan2 -j wanin
-A FORWARD -o vlan2 -j wanout
-A FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
-A shlimit -m recent --set --name shlimit --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource
-A shlimit -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 4 --name shlimit --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -j DROP
-A triggers -p tcp -m tcp --dport 17000:18000 -j TRIGGER --trigger-type out --trigger-proto tcp --trigger-match 17000-18000 --trigger-relate 17000-18000
-A triggers -p udp -m udp --dport 17000:18000 -j TRIGGER --trigger-type out --trigger-proto udp --trigger-match 17000-18000 --trigger-relate 17000-18000
-A wanin -j TRIGGER --trigger-type in --trigger-proto --trigger-match 0-0 --trigger-relate 0-0
-A wanin -d 192.168.1.118/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A wanin -d 192.168.1.118/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A wanout -j triggers
```

The IP address is correct as the server returns a login web page when I type in the host name on the network. However, it fails outside the network. I'm not sure what the issue is? Could it be an issue with the AT&T ISP or the BGW320 router? Also I'm not sure why port 8080 is reachable outside the network and inside as well?

Setup: AT&T ISP >-ONT AUTH-> BGW320 Router/Gateway >-IP Pass through-> R7000 Fresh Tomato Router > OpenVPN & HTTPS Web Portal Servers

BGW320 Router had a reset performed. Firewall and WiFi is disabled on the BGW320 Router.

https://forums.att.com/conversations/att-fiber-equipment/forwarded-port-is-closed-filtered-outside-the-network-and-open-inside-the-network/63827e3ec46ec145737c0e1a

Comment: My setup is a a Fresh Tomato Netgear R7000 router sitting behind an AT&T BGW320 router through IP pass through.